# jQuery UI Draggable/Sortable - Get reference to new item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using the jQuery UI Draggable/Sortable demo (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable) for the basis of my project. I need to get a reference to the `<li>` that gets cloned into the sortable when the sortable receives it. I tried the sortable's receive event, but that only gives a reference to the original draggable `<li>`, and not its clone.

Comment: yes i'm using the clone helper...trying to get a reference to the newly cloned <li>

Comment: had this exact problem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the demo you reference, there's actually a bug; after you drag an item down it inserts a cloned `li` with an `id` which is a duplicate of its brother's into the DOM, so beware (a [bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4564) was filed about this but there's no activity around it).

I did a few things to achieve this:

1. To get around the limitation of the demo that I described above, instead apply a `class` to the draggable items that will be linked to the `sortable`:

   ```
   <ul>
       <li class="new-item ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Make items with that class draggable, instead of selecting an element by `id`:

   ```
    $(".new-item").draggable({
        connectToSortable: "#sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
   ```
3. Tap into the [`stop` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) of the sortable, and perform some simple logic about the item that was dropped, leveraging the fact that an item with the class `new-item` could only have been dropped (and isn't simply an existing item in the sortable):

   ```
   $("#sortable").sortable({
       revert: true,
       stop: function(event, ui) {
           if (ui.item.hasClass("new-item")) {
               // This is a new item
               ui.item.removeClass("new-item");
               ui.item.html("<b>HI</b>");
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Note that you could use the `data-*` attribute instead of adding a helper class.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/twFCu/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for that, I was having a bit of trouble with this situation as well.

Comment: I was trying everything with the stop - on .draggable and getting nowhere - saved me a bunch of time, thanks

Comment: @reabow: Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

And if you want another very rough-and-ready way to get that item just to remove it or something, just reference it in the drop as

```
var _clone = $(".ui-draggable-dragging");
```

Of course that class is removed just AFTER the drop, so that reference gets lost and you can't do anything that isn't immediate.

The answer above is more robust but if you're in a crazy rush...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't fear accessing the `Sortable`'s internal state, you can do the following:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
  receive: function() {
    // Sortable.currentItem refers to the item just added.
    // jQuery UI < 1.10 uses "sortable" as its data key,
    // jQuery UI >= 1.10 defines an "instance" method to get the current instance.
    var $item =
      (
        $('#sortable').data('sortable') || // jQuery UI < 1.10
        $('#sortable').sortable('instance') // jQuery UI >= 1.10
      ).currentItem;
  }
);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t33bt/12/

Keep in mind though, that this might not work in a future jQuery UI version anymore because *it doesn't use the official API*. But nonetheless it works even in jQuery UI 1.11 (current version as of time of this writing).