# Using jQueryUI sortable and draggable causes container inline-block elements for sortable element to jump

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Related question on stackoverflow [0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354630/jqueryui-manipulate-draggable-clone) and [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876632/connecting-a-draggable-to-sortable-causes-helper-element-to-jump).
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashugupt/hpncs/1/

Also tried sortable as below:

```
$(".fields").sortable({
        connectedWith: ".fields",
        revert: true,
    });
```

P.S. You need to drag towards the bottom of the green div (between red and green) as in the snapshot[image: misbehaving sortable container]

Comment: I have made some changes. See if this solution works for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/hpncs/3/

Comment: @MandeepJain the float:left instead of display:inline-block solves the issue for me. Only addition I needed to make was to make $(#sortable).css({overflow: hidden}) [ofcourse, the equivalent in css file]. Put that fiddle change as answer and I'll mark it correct answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/hpncs/3/) works for you.

I basically changed your structure from

```
display: inline-block;
```

to

```
float: left;
```

Comment: I'm glad that I found this solution, even though I have pulled all of my hair out by now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative margin-bottom to the .ui-sortable-placeholder worked for me.
The amount may be related to your line-height so you may need to play with the number

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
    margin-bottom:-15px
}
```