# Draggable losses all its jQuery data after being dropped into a connected sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

jQuery draggable is losing all its connected jQuery data after joining a connected sortable list .. 
Also the reference of the dropped object is not the same as the object which joined sortable list .. 
Explanation and solution are required

Comment: Provide some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been already recorded as a bug in jQeuryUI itself
;.;

the draggable which is received in connected sortable is indeed a whole new different clone instead of being the original draggable itself. ..

Well friends !
A nice workaround solved my problem .. very well explained on this page ..

[jQuery UI Draggable/Sortable - Get reference to new item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973339/jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-get-reference-to-new-item)